# Does SSRS use compression when retrieving sql results?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

When Reporting Services runs the query for the report and retrieves the resultset, are the data results compressed in some way to limit the size of the data? As an extreme example, if there is one column (out of several) with the same value for all 100,000 records in the resultset, does SSRS know to only bring back one value so as to save sending excessive data over the network?

I'm referring to the data retrieval phase, not after processing/rendering.

SSRS 2008 / 2012

Comment: Reporting services brings back exactly what your dataset brings back.  If your dataset brings back 10,000 records, rs has to process all of this data.  It does not compress anything.

Comment: @Gabe What makes you think it would compress things?